# Set value to a class variable whose name matches to a string data

Tags: java, class

**Scenario**

I have a list of strings which resembles the names of class variables of a a class. So now i have to set values to those variables using the list.

**Example**

```
class Abc {
 private String name;
 private String Id;
 private String sal;
}

public static void main(String args[]){
Map<String,String> variablesMap = new HashMap<String,String>();
variablesMap.add("name","Joshi");
variablesMap.add("id","101");

/*Here i want to write the code to set the values for those variables*/
}
```

**Tried**

Class `ABC` contains all getters and setters. 
Using `java.lang.Field` class i can get the list of variables by `ABC.class.getDeclaredFileds()`. But after that how do i set the values for those.

Comment: [Field.set](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#set-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Object-)? By the way, it is `java.lang.reflect.Field`

Comment: Your code only has the *names* of the fields - to what *values* do you want to set them?

Comment: @Bohemian edited the question to set the values.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose field.set("name","joshi") does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a `Field` for your given name via `Field field = getClass().getDeclaredField(name);`

Then have a look at the Java Docs: [Field Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html)
There you have multiple options to set the value for your variable according to the data type.

Have a look at this example: **EDIT**: updated to suit your exact question

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class FieldTest {

    String name;
    String id;


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new FieldTest();
    }

    public FieldTest() {
    Map<String,String> variablesMap = new HashMap<String,String>();
    variablesMap.put("name","Joshi");
    variablesMap.put("id","101");

    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : variablesMap.entrySet())
    {
        try {
        test(entry.getKey(),entry.getValue());
        }
        catch(NoSuchFieldException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    System.out.println(name);
    System.out.println(id);
    }

    private void test(String name, String value) throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException {
        Field field = getClass().getDeclaredField(name);
        field.set(this,value);
    }

}
```

Comment: That works!!. One more doubt. If i have a local variable of name "nameString", i have the same list where i have "name" as value. Now i want to set value to "nameString" using that "name" data. How can i do that.?

Comment: Not quite sure what you want. You have this entry `    variablesMap.put("nameString","name");` and want to set "name" to the variable "nameString" ? Since the for loop iterates over the map entries it will be already done. Just add the variable to your class and the entry to your map.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use reflection for this.
say for variable 'name' you have a method getName() in class ABC.

so,
create a method name by iterating your variables map.
then get a method name in string,

```
String nameMethod = "getName";
Object obj=null;
try 
{
  method = getClass().getMethod(nameMethod);
  obj= method.invoke(this);//if blank then method return null for integer and date column
}
catch(NoSuchMethodException e) {

}
```

you can not use this snippet as it is,  you need to make some modifications

Answer (score 1):

You have to tell the Field which instance to set the values of:

```
ABC abc = new ABC();
for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : variablesMap.entrySet())
    ABC.class.getDeclaredField(entry.getKey()).set(abc, entry.getValue());
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use reflection to set the value of your fields.

One option is to use the `set()` method of a Field:

```
getClass().getDeclaredField(myFieldName).set(myObject, myValue);
```

If you want to use the setter method to set the value, you need to generate the name of the method. And set the value using `invoke()`:

```
String methodName = "set" + myFieldName.subString(0, 1).toUpperCase() + myFieldName.subString(1);
Method method = getClass().getMethod(methodName, String.class);
method.invoke(myObject, myValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        //abc is instance of class ABC
        BeanInfo info = Introspector.getBeanInfo(abc.getClass(),Object.class);
        PropertyDescriptor[] props1 = info.getPropertyDescriptors();
        for (PropertyDescriptor pd : props1) {
            String name = pd.getName();
            String arg1 = variablesMap.get(name);
            Method setter = pd.getWriteMethod();
            setter.invoke(abc, arg1);
        }
```